# How to use patchValue in Angular 2 Reactive form for fb.array elements

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, reactive

I have a reactive form:

```
myForm = this.fb.group({
    ...
}
```

and I update fields via buttons with functions like this:

```
(click)="update('someKey',someValue)"
```

where that function looks like this:

```
update(key, value) {
    if (key && value && this.myForm.contains(key)) {
        this.myForm.controls[key].patchValue(value)
    }
}
```

This works great, and I can use the same function for any form element by sending its name as the key.

However - now I have an fb.array in the form:

```
myForm = this.fb.group({
   ...
   items: this.fb.array([]),
}
```

Where:

```
items: {"name":"", "description":"")
```

And I need to be able to update the array values the same way.
How do I change

```
this.myForm.controls[key].patchValue(value)
```

To access the `fb.array`? I can pass the index of the array element I’m trying to access.

So something like:

```
(click)="update(index,'someKey',someValue)"


this.myForm.controls[items(index).controls[key].patchValue(value)
```

Or

```
this.myForm.get(`items${index}.${key}`).patchValue(value)
```

But this isn't correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is *always* the way, immediately after posting the question I'm presented with an answer in another forum (Thank you andreysuperstar!)

```
this.myForm.get(`items.${index}.${key}`).patchValue(value)
```

I was missing the dot between `items` and `${index}`

That will do the trick!